# How to create Microsoft Outlook Coded UI Extension plug in

Tags: .net, coded-ui-tests

I have a Autonomy/IManage (Document management system) application which is integrated in Microsoft outlook which provides you the result as a different mail items section in columns like title,version of document, author etc. I need to automate this application using Coded UI, but I am not able to select on the results which comes like an inbox results in another mail item section.
I searched on the net to find an alternative other than plug in to capture those results , but not able to find apart from coded ui extension plugin.

Is there  any way to capture those items from outlook? Or if I need to get a coded ui extension plugin , could somebody provide that who has already had a plugin for this.

Answer (score 2):

I did it through OOM. I used the sender's emailaddress and the email subject to find a mail. The code is as follows.

```
private string SelectMail(string addressTag, string subject)

{
    Outlook.Application app = new Outlook.Application();
    Outlook.Explorer explorer = app.ActiveExplorer();
    explorer.ClearSelection();

    string senderEmail = Utils.Setting.Get(addressTag);

    IEnumerable<Outlook.MailItem> selectedMails = from Outlook.MailItem mailItem in explorer.CurrentFolder.Items
                                                  where mailItem.SenderEmailAddress == senderEmail && mailItem.Subject == subject
                                                  select mailItem;
    Outlook.MailItem mail = selectedMails.FirstOrDefault<Outlook.MailItem>();

    explorer.AddToSelection(mail);

    return mail.Subject;
}
```